# Distribute records on different MySQL databases - MySQL Proxy alternative

Tags: mysql, distributed-databases, mysql-proxy

My scenario is the following:

Right now I am using one big MySQL database with multiple tables to store user data. Many tables contain auto increment columns.

I would like to split this into 2 or more databases. The distribution should be done by user_id and is determined (cannot be randomized). E.g. user 1 and 2 should be on database1, user 3 on database2, user 4 on database3.
Since I don't want to change my whole frontend, I would like to still use one db adapter and kind of add a layer between the query generation (frontend) and the query execution (on the right database). This layer should distribute the queries to the right database based on the user_id.

I have found [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) which sounds exactly like what I need. Unfortunately, it's in alpha and not recommended to be used in a production environment.
For php there is [MySQL Native Driver Plugin API](http://www.php.net/manual/fa/mysqlnd.plugin.php) which sounds promising but then I need a layer that supports at least php *and* java.

Is there any other way I can achieve my objectives? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into [MySQL Fabric](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/fabric.html) ([Official Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/fabric.html)) but it requires more db server

I have tried this tool only in R&D env for testing a basic HA

It supports some [sharding scenarios](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/fabric-quick-start-sharding.html)

Here some high level pros and cons

Pros:

- setup
- sharding
- write/read
- basic HA

Cons:

- fabric node is the SPOF
- no multi master
- rewrite software in order to use the fabric driver